# How to programatically set a property that remains in a UITableViewCell after reloading datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with the following layout

```
TableView
 -> CustomCell
 --> CustomLabel
```

My custom label has some drawing code that if a property `@property (nonatomic) bool animated;` is `YES`, it will draw the contents animated, and if it is `NO`, will draw it's contents without animation.

By default `bool animated` is `NO`.

So when the table view intially loads it's data and redraws the cell, the content is draw without animation.

Now this is where I become unstuck.

The effect I'm after is that when a user clicks the cell, the data for the cell is updated and the content gets redrawn animated.

I trigger this like so,

```
[sender setTitle:newValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.noteTitle.animated = YES;
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathOfTheCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The problem is that while I am setting,

```
cell.noteTitle.animated = YES;
```

when I call

```
cell.noteTitle.animated = YES;
```

it seems to create a new instance of the `CustomCell` which as I've described above, has `animated = NO`.

So my question is this, how can I call my draw my custom cell, so that it doesn't animate the when table loads the cell, but does animate when the user changes the cell value.

Comment: You will need to show more code. I guess that especially cellForRowAtIndexPath is required. It may well be that we have to have a look at the code of your custom cell and label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was rewriting this question, I stumbled upon the answer.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I store the current selected path,  then in

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if the current cell being drawn in the one that was selected, then set the animated property accordingly

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:self.currentSelectedIndexPath]){
    cell.noteTitle.animated = YES;
}else{
     cell.noteTitle.animated = NO;
}
```

Thanks for the help guys, I realise I should have included more code in the original question

Answer (score 0):

this code is not enough to analyze the problem.

as per what I get you can try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Do your work "[sender setTitle:newValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];" 
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathOfTheCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

**Note : need more code for correct answer**

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the cell from cell for row index and try operating on that cell.

```
CustomCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowIndex:index]; //this will reference that cell
cell.noteTitle.animated = yes;
[self.tableView reloadData];
cell = nil;
```